# django view didn't return an HttpResponse object when retrieving file

Tags: django

I've run into an issue when creating a custom view for processing requests for media file. I've customized it to be able to do custom permissions checks and overrides.

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', views.document_view, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

@login_required
def document_view(request, path, document_root):

    name = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    if not os.path.isfile(name):
        raise Http404("File not found.")
    if request.user.is_staff:
        print "staff"
        serve_document(request, path)
    else:
        print "FORBIDDEN"
        raise PermissionDenied

def serve_document(rcvd_request, path):

    print "Send " + path
    # set PRIVATE_MEDIA_USE_XSENDFILE in your deployment-specific settings file
    # should be false for development, true when your webserver supports xsendfile
    # This is currently zero
    if settings.PRIVATE_MEDIA_USE_XSENDFILE:

        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
        response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = filename # Nginx
        response['X-Sendfile'] = filename # Apache 2 with mod-xsendfile
        del response['Content-Type'] # let webserver regenerate this
        return response
    else:
        print "Fallback serve"
        # fallback method        
        return serve(rcvd_request, path, settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

    return serve(request, path, path, settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I click on a link that has the file linked to, I get

```
The view portal.views.dashboard.document_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

This doesn't make much sense since I know the serve gets called with the right path, the file exists (in fact a previous version without staff check worked in downloading the files.
I've seen people have issues due to indentation and function exiting with None as default, but this isn't the case.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. When I call the serve_document function, I need to add return since the return of the serve_document doesn't propagate to the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the following line of your `document_view`:

```
serve_document(request, path)
```

Django view expects an HttpResponse returned. But this line does not return anything. The response returned by `serve_document` is not assigned to anything nor returned.

Thus, you should change it to:

```
return serve_document(request, path)
```

or, make it more explicit:

```
http_response = serve_document(request, path)
return http_response
```